# CSS @media problems

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use the @media thingy in CSS and I ran into some problems.

Here is my CSS code (I have a massive screen):

```
#headerImage {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

The 1000px header image is just right for me on my big screen.
But since I'm making a website for a company, I have to consider about the viewer's screen size, so I researched on [W3Schools](https://w3schools.com) and found out about the @media thing.

So then, I put the @media thing into my CSS. Here's the @media:

```
@media only screen and (max-height: 700px) {
  #headerImage {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
  }
}
```

Good. I went back to the website, and reloaded it. `1000px`. Good. 
Now, I resized the **height** of the browser to something less than `700px`. (I made the height small so it's definitely <`700px`)
No. It's still `1000px`.

Is there anything wrong?

Edit:

NOTE: I am using Chrome Version 96.0.4664.110 (Official Build) (x86_64)

Here's a bit of my HTML:

```
<img id="headerImage" src="logo.png">
```

And also, do you need `<meta>`?
I have it here:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: `1000px` isn't "massive". My phone has a 4-inch screen with more pixels than that...

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong there. Try providing a [mcve]. Use the live demo feature of the question editor and http://placekitten.com

Comment: You need to post your HTML too y'know. Use StackOverflow's "Insert HTML+JS+CSS Snippet" button to show us a complete working example.

Comment: Also, hardcoding specific sizes (like `1000px` and `500px`, etc) is often **not** the best way to handle different types of browsers/clients/devices - consider using viewport-relative units instead, and you should specify `object-fit` whenever you use CSS to override the size of an `<img />` element, e.g. `#headerImage { width: 100vh; height: 50vh; object-fit: contain; }`.

Comment: @Dai — Keep in mind that CSS pixels and physical pixels are not the same thing, especially on ultra high resolution screens.

Comment: @Dai The `1000px` is just the size of my image. My screen is 3 times bigger than that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this once
you can try in mobile too height :100vh is you want full screen image

```
#headerImage {
    width: 100%;
    height:100vh;
  }
@media only screen and (max-height: 700px) {
  #headerImage {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

Comment: wait no thx I just changed the width to 100vh, and it works. Thanks!

Comment: if you want to keep aspect ratio then put width:100% and height: auto;
if you want to cover whole parent element then height:100% and width:100%